# Why not use React as Angular 2's View?

Tags: angular, reactjs, frontend

I understand that Angular is an MVC framework and React is just the V. I see this two technologies complementary, taking advantage of React’s virtual DOM rendering and state isolation combined with Angular’s MVC wholeness.

Are they really complementary/good fit? I haven't seen an angular project using react as view.

Comment: They do both mostly the same, just in a slightly different way.